# Set HTML title in Iron-Router without messing up browser history

Tags: meteor, iron-router

It's possible to set a per-route HTML title in Iron-Router using an `onAfterAction`:

```js
Router.route("home", {
  path: "/",
  template: "home",
  onAfterAction: function () {
    document.title = "Home";
  }
});

Router.route("pageA", {
  path: "/page/a",
  template: "pageA",
  onAfterAction: function () {
    document.title = "Page A";
  }
});

Router.route("pageB", {
  path: "/page/b",
  template: "pageB",
  onAfterAction: function () {
    document.title = "Page B";
  }
});

Router.route("pageC", {
  path: "/page/c",
  template: "pageC",
  onAfterAction: function () {
    document.title = "Page C";
  }
});
```

However, this causes the back-history to be messed up, at least on Chrome. If you start at Home, browse to A, then to B, then to C, then when right-clicking the back button you see:

- Page C   (clicking it takes you to Page B)
- Page B   (clicking it takes you to Page A)
- Page A   (clicking it takes you to Home)

What I want is:

- Page B   (clicking it takes you to Page B)
- Page A   (clicking it takes you to Page A)
- Home     (clicking it takes you to Home)

If you press back a few times and then right click on forward, the forward-history works correctly (but not the back-history).

Is there some other way to set the HTML title which supports the back history? Using an `onBeforeAction` or `onRun` instead of `onAfterAction` does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make use of templates' reactive properties. In your `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
  <title>My App {{#if extraTitle}}| {{extraTitle}}{{/if}}
</head>
```

Then from here, you can inject value into `extraTitle` in many ways. one of my favorites is creating a global helper:

```
Template.registerHelper('extraTitle', function() {
      // do something.
});
```

Do something could then be multiple possiblities. The easiest should be `Session.get`:

```
Template.registerHelper('extraTitle', function() {
      return Session.get("extraTitle");
});
```

So you could instead set the title using the following in your `onAfterActions` or wherever you need it.

```
Session.set("extraTitle", "current page.");
```

As i mentioned, there are multiple ways to do it other than `Session`, as long as it's a reactive data source like `ReactiveVar` perhaps. Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately `<head>` is not a proper reactive template. See this [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/s278oPZkihF2q5wuJ/Leaderboard) (click on the arrow in the top-right corner to open it in a new tab)